# How can I index a string containing @ when \index itself uses @?

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, makeindex

I need to index the string `$@`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\indexthing}[1]%
{%
    \index{#1@\texttt{#1} (thing)}%
    \index{things!\texttt{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{ch1}

foo\index{foo}
bar\index{bar}
\index{\$\@}      % PROBLEM A
\indexthing{\$\@} % PROBLEM B

\chapter{ch2}

baz\index{baz}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

If you comment out the PROBLEM B line the document compiles but `$` appears in the index instead of `$@`.

If you leave the PROBLEM B line in, it won't compile at all

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.17     \subitem m {}}
                       , 1
```

How do I include `@` in an index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the *quote* character to prefix the *actual* character:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\indexthing}[1]%
{%
    \index{#1@\texttt{#1} (thing)}%
    \index{things!\texttt{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{ch1}

foo\index{foo}
bar\index{bar}
\index{\$"@}      % PROBLEM A
\indexthing{\$"@} % PROBLEM B

\chapter{ch2}

baz\index{baz}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

The characters depend on the MakeIndex style. For more information see, e.g., section *INPUT STYLE SPECIFIERS* in the MakeIndex manual.